# Bad numerical approximations

Tags: numerics, vector-calculus

I'm trying to do some calculations here, but for some reason Mathematica starts using numerical approximations that are no good for my work. Specifically:

```
T[t_] := {(-Sin[t])/(Sqrt[1 + Cos[t/2]^2]), 
(Cos[t])/(Sqrt[1 + Cos[t/2]^2]), (Cos[t/2])/(Sqrt[1 + Cos[t/2]^2])}

B[t_] := {(-0.5 Cos[t] Sin[t/2] + Cos[t/2] Sin[t])/Sqrt[
  1.625 + 0.375 Cos[t]], (- Cos[t/2] Cos[t] - 
   0.5 Sin[t/2] Sin[t])/Sqrt[1.625 + 0.375 Cos[t]], 1/Sqrt[
  1.625 + 0.375 Cos[t]]}

Cross[B[t], T[t]]
```

After using `Simplify`, I get:

> `{((1.4142135623730951 + 1.4142135623730951 Cos[t/2]^2) Cos[t] + 
>     0.3535533905932738 Sin[t]^2)/(
>    Sqrt[1.625 + 0.375 Cos[t]] Sqrt[
>     3 + Cos[t]]), ((1 + Cos[t/2]^2 - 0.25 Cos[t]) Sin[t])/(
>    Sqrt[0.8125 + 0.1875 Cos[t]] Sqrt[3 + Cos[t]]), (0.7071067811865476 Sin[t/2])/(Sqrt[1.625 + 0.375 Cos[t]] Sqrt[3 + Cos[t]])}`

I know for a fact that: $$1.4142135623730951 \approx \sqrt{2} \\ 0.7071067811865476 \approx \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \\ 0.3535533905932738 \approx \frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}$$

When I write `Sqrt[2]`, `(Sqrt[2]/2)` and `(Sqrt[2]/4)` instead of these numbers, I am unable to proceed with these calculations, and I keep getting the warning: [image]

etc. Can someone tell me how to solve this?

---

I didn't know what tag or specific title to put here, so if you have a better idea, feel free to edit it.

Comment: Try defining `B[t] := Rationalize@ {(-0.5 Cos[t] Sin[t/2] + Cos[t/2] Sin[t])/Sqrt[ 1.625 + 0.375 Cos[t]], (- Cos[t/2] Cos[t] - 0.5 Sin[t/2] Sin[t])/Sqrt[1.625 + 0.375 Cos[t]], 1/Sqrt[ 1.625 + 0.375 Cos[t]]}` instead

Comment: It did not work :(

Comment: There's a backtick there that shouldn't be. My guess is that you copy-pasted Sqrt[2] over the real, but the real has a trace backtick which you didn't see, or mind. Remove that backtick.

Comment: What difference do they make? When initially typing, I just typed everything without the backticks and had no problems at all.

Comment: When typing reals backticks indicate precision. To be honest, I find them mostly useless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
T[t_] := {(-Sin[t])/(Sqrt[1 + Cos[t/2]^2]), 
          (Cos[t])/(Sqrt[1 + Cos[t/2]^2]), 
          (Cos[t/2])/(Sqrt[1 + Cos[t/2]^2])}

B[t_] := Rationalize@{(-0.5 Cos[t] Sin[t/2] + Cos[t/2] Sin[t]) Sqrt[1.625 + 0.375 Cos[t]], 
                      (-Cos[t/2] Cos[t] - 0.5 Sin[t/2] Sin[t])/Sqrt[1.625 + 0.375 Cos[t]], 
                       1/Sqrt[1.625 + 0.375 Cos[t]]}

Cross[B[t], T[t]] // FullSimplify // TeXForm
```

$\left\{-\frac{12 \cos (t)+\cos (2 t)+3}{2 \sqrt{\cos (t)+3} \sqrt{3 \cos
   (t)+13}},-\frac{\sin (t) (\cos (t)+6)}{\sqrt{\cos (t)+3} \sqrt{3 \cos
   (t)+13}},-\frac{2 \sin \left(\frac{t}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{\cos (t)+3}
   \sqrt{3 \cos (t)+13}}\right\}$

Comment: Cross[B[t], T[t]] // Simplify will give a significantly simpler form.

Comment: @BobHanlon Thanks. Done

Comment: @belisarius I just noticed your new photo. Albeit Argentina produced & produces so many wonderful imaginations, I'm not aware of the fact that it was ever engaged in boxing :)

Comment: @eldo Argentina has a long history of very good boxers and [world champions](http://boxrec.com/media/index.php/Category:Argentine_World_Champions). In particular Nicolino Locche was in my book one of the quickest defensive boxers. If you like boxing, take a look at [this round](http://youtu.be/GCxgODaBiBw?t=7m40s), from the fight when he won the world championship. (Ps: Paul Fuji was crying in impotence that night when he left the ring)